# Add layout for custom field

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-field

How can i add an additional layout for repeatable.php of the custom fields in my template?

So i want to create repeatable_image.php and make it available in layout render option of the custom field.

Where so i have to place it?

Here i can override it, but i want to add a layout (no override of the render.php):

/web/templates/mytemplate/html/plg_fields_repeatable/repeatable.php

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the field view, which you can make available in the layout option of the field, this is a good tutorial learn how to do it: [#7. Alternative layouts for custom fields](https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/joomla-39/)

Look at number #7

If you want to override the form field, create these files inside /web/templates/mytemplate/html:

1. layouts/joomla/form/field/subform/repeatable-table.php
2. layouts/joomla/form/field/subform/repeatable.php